# LINQ ArgumentException due to AnonymousObject

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to `Union` two `IQueryables` of the same type but am hit with the following error

`An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The input sequence must have items of type 'MyProject.Data.Entities.Project', but it has items of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AnonymousObject'.'`

Basically I am taking a list of `Projects` and separating those that have `Any() ProjectActivities` out into their own list - I am then sorting them by the `Activity Name` before finally attempting to `Union` the original `Projects` back in.

My code was originally:

```
IQueryable<Project> projectsWithActivities = projects
            .Where(x => x.ProjectActivities.Any())
projects = projectsWithActivities
                    .OrderBy(u => u.ProjectActivities
                        .OrderBy(p => p.Activity.Name)
                    .FirstOrDefault().Activity.Name)
                    .AsQueryable()
                    .Union(projects);
```

Note that `projects` is an existing `IQueryable<Project>` passed in as a method argument.

After some research I believed that the cause of my error was because the `Where` was causing `projectsWithActivities` to become an `AnonymousObject` and to overcome this issue I had to `Select` into a new `Project` Object so I changed my code to:

```
IQueryable<Project> projectsWithActivities = projects
            .Where(x => x.ProjectActivities.Any())
            .Select(x => new Project(){Id = x.Id, SomeProperty = x.SomeProperty,
                etc etc});
```

However, this made no difference, I am still faced with the above error.

Also if you are wondering why I am separating a list of `Projects` out and then trying to merge them back in, it's because some `Projects` do not have any `ProjectActivities` and therefore whenever I attempt to sort by the `Activity Name` it falls over on a null reference.

Could somebody please shed some light on what I am doing wrong - I am still very much learning basic Linq and so I am completely stumped on this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you talk us through why you felt the need to explicitly add `.AsQueryable()`? Does it work if you remove it?

Comment: I noticed that `OrderBy` returns an `IEnumerable` and so I thought the issue was because I was trying to `Union` an `IEnumerable` and an `IQueryable` but no unfortunately it does not work with or without it.

Comment: If you remove the `AsQueryable`, what is the **exact error**?

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from the lines you have shown, what are you passing to the function? The argument will be evaluated when necessary so the exception might be coming from that. I ran the above linq queries on dummy data and saw no exception.

Comment: @mjwills whenever I remove `AsQueryable` I get the error: `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The input sequence must have items of type 'MyProject.Entities.Project', but it has items of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AnonymousObject'.'`

Comment: @peeyushsingh The code in the original question is in my `SortProjects` method to which I pass the `IQueryable` `projects`. After it has sorted the projects it returns them and the code falls over on the immediate next line which is:
`model.ProjectModels = PaginatedList<ProjectModel>.Create(projects.ToList().Select(project => ProjectModel.ToModel(project)).AsQueryable(), page ?? 1, this.Options.RowsPerPage);`

Comment: IQueryable/IEnumerable are deffered type, i.e they are not executed when you build them. The execution would be happening when you call project.ToList() and that is where the error is happening, but the actual reason would be in one of the existing queries, and thats why I said that the error might be in the IQueryable Projects which you pass into the sorted method

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the OrderBy.
Could you isolate the issue by just running a simple OrderBy or another linq operation on the projectsWithActivities? Something like

```
projectsWithActivities.OrderBy(p = > ProjectActivities.Count)
```

Then add the other operations one by one.

Comment: Hmm, by only ordering by `ProjectActivities.Count` the code makes it past where it currently falls over, but then falls over later on an unrelated null pointer reference which I will need to fix next I guess!

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error in a Union or Concat, it probably means there is an error with one of the subqueries. Pull the subquery out of the statement and evaluate the results in the debugger to see what the error is.